# Uploading report.json manually to sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have a report.json file obtained by running sonar scanner on a java project. Instead of conventional way of uploading this report to sonarqube, I need to manually upload this report to sonarqube. How to achieve the same?

Comment: Are you looking for of menu-option of some kind?

Comment: Yes. Somthing like that would suffice

Comment: You don't find that. Maybe the WEB API has a usable method for you.

Comment: I have found the desired post rest api for the same [link](https://next.sonarqube.com/sonarqube/web_api/api/ce/submit?internal=true). here **POST api/ce/submit** is the desired api. BUt not able to get the desited value for parameter report